# Different error messages for same vaildation Keyword in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, unique

I need for the validation keyword 'unique' two different error messages. How to do this? Is there any function for unique which I can copy and rename it?

```
'unique'               => 'The :Attribute has already been taken.',
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by description, do you mean the error message when the validation fails?  Provide some code and more context..

Comment: Yes, error messages.

Comment: Did you read the manual?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-error-messages

Comment: share where you want which message , if any condition please share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-error-messages

**Specifying A Custom Message For A Given Attribute**

Sometimes you may wish to specify a custom error messages only for a specific field. You may do so using "dot" notation. Specify the attribute's name first, followed by the rule:

```
$messages = [
    'email.required' => 'We need to know your e-mail address!',
];
```

---

Replace email with the field name and required with unique.

Comment: How to do this for my statement? $this->validate($request, [
            'Gruppe' => 'unique:groups_request,idgroups'
            ]);